# Div label blurry compared with placeholder text

Tags: html, css

I can't get the text identical between a DIV label and an input placeholder label:

[image]

CSS for the Dropdowns:

```
.title {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #606060;
}
```

CSS for placeholder:

```
input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
    color: #606060;
    font-size: 14px;
}

input:-moz-placeholder { /* Firefox 18- */
    color: #606060;
    font-size: 14px;
}

input::-moz-placeholder {  /* Firefox 19+ */
    color: #606060;
    font-size: 14px;
}

input:-ms-input-placeholder {  
    color: #606060;
    font-size: 14px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="title">Serviço?</div>
<ul>
    <li>Centros</li>
    <li>Vidros</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What is a "div label"? Please show us the full HTML & CSS

Comment: Hi sorry, I have updated the question. I realized that in IE is does not look so obvious but in Chrome (like the picture) it is.

Comment: There are no inputs in your HTML...

Answer (score 0):

This "blur" is caused by the text-shadow property. Set it to none :

```
placeholder {
text-shadow: none;
}
```

Comment: This is not clear in the question. Please use the "Code snippet" button to provide a working example.